# powershell syntax error:invalidsyntax(python27)

Tags: python-2.7, powershell

Just started to learn Python from 'learn python the hard way' book, but when the author types Python in Power-Shell and then type `^Z` subsequently , I got syntax error at `^Z`.

Can someone please help?

My current directory is `C:/users/wef/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^Z` is not something you can type. If you type it literally like that at the interactive Python prompt, you will get the syntax error you see:

```
>>> ^Z
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    ^Z
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Instead, `^Z` is a *control character* that is inserted by pressing [<kbd>Ctrl + Z</kbd>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-Z). At command prompts, this control character usually refers to [end-of-file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file).

When using the interactive Python interpreter, you can use this sequence to tell the interpreter that you will not enter any further commands, i.e. it’s the “end of file” of your input. So as a result, the interpreter will exit.

An other way to exit the interpreter is to call the `exit()` function.